# Tracking file in Netbeans IDE Projects window

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, ide

Just getting hands on with NetBeans 8.0.2. Wondering if the IDE has similar features as Eclipse or Visual Studio like

1. Track current file in Projects explorer - When working with large projects, with lots of files open, if I want to navigate to current file in projects window it is getting difficult.
2. On top of it, the project explorer is showing the folders/files in a case sensitive manner resulting difficult to locate the exact file/folder.

Is there a settings or two to control this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part:

use the option "View -> Synchronized Editor with views" to automatically select the current file in the editor in the project window.

Alternatively (what I prefer) use "Navigate -> Select in Projects" to manually select the current editor file in the project window .

You can find more information about navigating in the IDE in the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/work_java_code.htm#CIAGADFI

Regarding the second part: Java is case sensitive. `MyClass` is something different than `MyCLASS` so it has to treat the file names as case sensitive.